# How to pause and play media player when screen is locked or sleeps?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am using Java and xml to create an application for the summer. This app has music in the background, that I would like to pause and then play depending on the state it is in. When i lock my screen the music does not pause it keeps playing. How would i fix this, I have tried to use the method on this site:

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents

I have not been able to successfully get a working prototype, and I am working in android studio.

```
        myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c(this is the context), myField(This is the raw file));
        myPlayer.start();
        myPlayer.setLooping(true);
        myPlayer.setVolume(0.7f,0.7f);
```

What could I add to pause the mediaplayer when the lock button is pressed or the phone goes to sleep and then play it when the phone is unlocked?

Comment: If you are in an activity, you can use onPause and onResume

Comment: I am actually passing the context and raw file to a non activity class which deals with the media player and it's functions. I have about 3 activities and each time they are created they call the non activity class and pass in those arguments.

Comment: So you create onPause and onResume in the class and call those methods from the activity you are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (myPlayer != null) {
            myPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (myPlayer != null) {
            myPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @LunarWatcher gave me another suggestion it worked. I also tried yours and worked perfectly as well. Thank you for your help!